# Broadcast receiver not being triggered

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to create a service which will trigger a broadcast receiver when the location changes. But for some reason my broadcast receiver doesnt get triggered. I have added the necessary permissions for location. Any help will be appreciated. I am starting the service in my main activity.In my broadcast receiver I am restarting the service so that my app will continuously send location updates to the server.

My broadcast receiver class:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


   // updateLocationServer();
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,LocationService.class);
    Log.i("in broadcast","in");
    String latitude = intent1.getStringExtra("latitude");
    String longitude = intent1.getStringExtra("longitude");
    Log.i("lat",latitude);
    Log.i("lat",longitude);

    updateLocationServer(latitude,longitude);
    context.startService(intent1);

}
```

My service class:

```
public class LocationService extends Service
{

    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;

    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 20000, 0, listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000, 0, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }



    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }




    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {

            Log.i("lat1", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
            Log.i("lat2", String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
            intent.putExtra("Latitude", loc.getLatitude());
            intent.putExtra("Longitude", loc.getLongitude());

            sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {

        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {

        }


        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }

    }




}
```

Static registration in the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".helper.MyBroadcastReceiver"
     >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Hello World" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Have you registered your broadcast receiver?

Comment: Yes I have. Done the edits.

Comment: If you are doing it via code, you have to manually called sendBroadcast api. Its available on all usual contexts...

Comment: @sandy Remove space from the action name

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the receiver configuration in the manifest below...the action strings should both be the same

Comment: I have removed the spaces in the names, still doesn work:(

Comment: thanks for your help. it worked:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first in manifest

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.Hello World" >
```

line change to

```
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.HelloWorld" >
```

after in My service class

```
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
```

to

```
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "android.intent.action.HelloWorld";
```

Comment: Removed the spaces from the action names in both places.Still doesnt work

Comment: in class BROADCAST_ACTION = "android.intent.action.HelloWorld";  try this